Do mini-humans need a "real" Saturn V to reach the moon?
What if humans would not be in the scale we know, but being much smaller. If they wanted to go to the moon in the 1960s, would they have had to build a "real sized" Saturn V because of the immense amounts of fuel (or something else) needed? Or is it possible to build a downsized one and reach the moon equally well? Or is the moon not reachable at all for some reason?
Scenario

For the matter of scaling, a mini-human shall be 17.5cm (0.175m) tall on average (that is about 6.8 inch). Thus you could assume a scaling factor of 1:10 if need arises for the argumentation (It is a overall scaling factor, applying not to size alone)

If possible, smaller factors would be preferable, scaled by 1/100 to a size of 1.75cm (about half an inch) for a mini-human for example.

I assume mini-humans being "us normies" just smaller, having the same capabilities in technology, tools, man-power, etc.

The planet and the rest of the universe is not altered. Same size, same G-forces (does this make sense?), same atmosphere, same distance to the moon.

Delivery times of resources etc. that have to be brought in are not considered to take longer. That is handwaved.

Prototype for the mission is Apollo-11, designated to land on the moon in 1969. On board: Microbuzz Aldrin, Neil Microstrong and in the command module Michael Microllins (Buzz, Neal and Mike for short).


Question
Can mini-humans land on the moon and get back safely to earth again? What does this imply for the Saturn V rocket?
For the Answers

Ideally, I am seeking a mathematical proof (rocket equation hobbyist someone?) or a conclusive thought experiment to proof or disproof things.

Focus: I am mainly interested in the size or feasibility of the rocket. Not so much on the logical/biological justification of the mini-humans (dubbed micronauts by AlexP).

Disproof: What are the laws of physics standing against the downscaling? Please give some reference, a link to wikipedia, at least name the law or principle so I can research myself.

Clarification 1960s Tech and Computers:
True, they were large and handcrafted that time. But micro-nauts have micro-hands (as were stated in one of the answers/comments). So they would be able to manufacture smaller devices as well. UNLESS there are physical constraints which do not allow shrinking of electrical components beyond a certain limit without having high-tech available (like transistors, ICs, LEDs, 6nm-CPU-manufacturing etc.). Therefore it should stay at 1960s tech-level to answer the bottom-line question.
What those constraints could be? I don't know really, therefore I ask. A strong hint was throughput of fuel pipes etc. When the diameter of pipes shrink, pressure or other things do not scale linearly? Also maybe material strengths. Definitely physical constraints for radio equipment for example (wavelengths -> antenna size) was identified. Radiation shielding maybe also. There would be some biological aspects as well, wether micro-nauts are less or more resistant to radiation because of their scaled size. Rope-Memory maybe? micro-Amperes through micro-wire?


Addendum

For those who are interested:
Can we scale down humans to the size of a mouse? I stumbled across this by accident now/afterwards.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Let's ask a simpler, but equivalent question:
If it takes a rocket of a certain size to send three people on a given mission (e.g. a Saturn V to go to the moon), can a smaller rocket be used to send less people on the same mission?
We know the answer to this question is "yes", because that's exactly what happened. To put one (American) person into orbit required the Mercury capsule, weighing 1400kg, launched on an Atlas rocket weighing about 120 metrics tons. Two people required a Gemini module, weighing 3800kg, launched on a Titan II at about 155 tons. Three people required an Apollo CM (not the full Apollo CSM that went to the moon) weighing almost 5600kg and launched on a Saturn IB weighing 590 metric tons (for the earth-orbital Apollo 7 mission). Put simply, you can fit less people into smaller capsules, and smaller capsules can be launched on smaller rockets.
There's nuance to that, of course. The Titan II is only about 25% heavier than the Atlas, because the Atlas was not purpose-built as a launch vehicle but was repurposed from an ICBM. The weight differences from Mercury to Gemini to Apollo are not just from the extra capacity - there was additional equipment and longer mission durations, for example. But the principal still stands, and was much the same for the Russian Vostok, Voskhod and Soyuz modules - more astronauts means more equipment, volume & mass, and so bigger rockets, and so less astronauts (or, smaller astronauts) means less mass and smaller rockets.
So it's not all a direct correlation. Some things, like the amount of supplies, the number/size of seats, and the size/capacity of the life support systems will directly scale with astronaut count & size. These are smaller masses, like 550kg for crew couches & provisions, 200kg for the Environmental Control System or 15kg for drinking water, out of a total CM mass of 5600kg.
Other things, like the weight of the radiation shielding, insulation, pressure vessel and heat shield (the bulk of the weight, almost 1600kg for the structure & 850kg for the heat shield) scale by the exterior surface area of the module, which increases as more volume is needed, either for the astronauts themselves or the space required for their support systems. If your astronauts and their systems only take up 1/10th the volume, then you require 1/4.6 as much surface area - still a substantial decrease.
Then you have things which are absolutely bound by the technology of the time, such as the electronics. The physical interfaces (dials, lights) and batteries are probably going to be smaller, but a circuit is going to be exactly the size that the technology of the 1960s allows - those account for e.g. 500 kg for Navigation Equipment, 700 kg for Electrical, 200kg for Telemetry and 100 kg for Communication.
So, short version, a module carrying 1/10th the mass of astronauts to the moon and back will weigh more than 1/10th of the Apollo CM - but it's going to be more like 1/5th, 1/4th or 1/3rd.
After that things should be mostly proportional - if you reduce the mass of the payload to a third, you'll only need a third of the fuel, RCS mass, etc. It's not perfect, of course, as you expend fuel to counter air resistance or to directly counter gravity as you launch, but as we're still talking about a dry payload of 1-2 metrics tons, with a starting rocket mass of maybe 750-1000 tons, it still approximately holds. If you were to scale down to hobby rockets launching 50g action figures into orbit, then those inefficiencies become a dominant factor.
And even though we're talking about a multi-stage mission, each stage's weight is derived from the one after. The total Apollo CSM was maybe 30 tons, but that comprised of the fuel and oxidiser to push a 5600 kg command module through lunar insertion and trans-earth injection burns. If you make the command module 1/3rd the size, then you only need 1/3rd the fuel (and 1/3rd the tanks, and 1/3rd the support structure, and...) in the CSM. If the CSM is 1/3rd the mass, you only need 1/3rd the size of the second stage for trans-lunar injection, and then 1/3rd the first stage to get to Earth orbit.
Again, it's never a perfect conversion, especially as changing the size of the engine is going to affect its efficiency, thrust-to-weight ratio and so on, but broadly speaking it holds.
Hopefully that gives you some ideas for your micronauts! The numbers I used in the estimates I got from Encyclopedia Astronautica and Apollo By The Numbers.
Edit - Changes in rocket size with payload
To clarify for folks in the comments asking why we don't still need a massive rocket to lift all the rocket fuel, and lay out the problem with @JBH 's answer, let's run a demonstration.
First, let's show our payload - we'll start with one astronaut at e.g. 60Kg, with each 20Kg shown as ():
()()()

Now, let's put them on our first, tiny rocket. We'll build this rocket to be capable of 2km/s of delta-v to start, using the rocket equation to determine the size.
Rocket Equation
$\Delta v = v_e \ln \left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)$
where delta-v equals the exhaust velocity of the rocket, multiplied by the natural logarithm of the mass ratio (total or starting rocket mass over final rocket mass, also called wet mass to dry mass).
Re-arranged to give the mass ratio:
$\frac{m_0}{m_f} = e^{\frac{\Delta v}{v_e}}$
$v_e$ is the specific impulse of the engine (for Apollo 11, this ranged from 250s to 400s, so we'll conservatively average at 300s - typical for liquid fuel rockets) multiplied by $g_0$ - Earth's gravity - at 9.81. $\Delta v$ is 2000m/s as mentioned above, giving:
$\frac{m_0}{m_f} = e^{\frac{2000}{300 * 9.81}} = e^{0.68} = 1.974$
So to move our astronaut through 2Km/s of acceleration, the total mass of the astronaut plus the fuel must be (approx) twice the mass of the astronaut - or put another way, we need as much fuel by mass as we have astronaut. I'll use /\ to indicate 20Kgs of fuel:
()()()
/\/\/\

So far so good. To accelerate another 2Km/s, we add another layer of fuel to our rocket; still at the 2:1 mass ratio, but now it must move the original astronaut payload and the fuel already in the rocket - 60Kg of astronaut plus 60Kg fuel is 120Kg of payload, so we need 120Kg of additional fuel:
   ()()()
   /\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\

Another 2Km/s, and another layer as large as all the previous layers combined:
         ()()()
         /\/\/\
      /\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

The rocket's starting to grow pretty fast, and we've only achieved 6Km/s of delta-v; the round-trip to lunar orbit & back, even without the LEM trip to the surface, is 14.2Km/s, more than seven layers of doubling fuel. For the purposes of our demonstration and to save wearing out my slash keys, let's stop at four layers:
                     ()()()
                     /\/\/\
                  /\/\/\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

Now, when we say "the majority of the rocket fuel is used to lift the rocket & its fuel", this is what we mean. As the rocket moves through each 2Km/s burn, only the chunk of fuel in the middle is used to move the actual astronaut:
                     ()()()
                     /\/\/\
                  /\/\/\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

                     ^^^^^^

Everything else is used to move the remaining fuel:
                     ()()()
                     /\/\/\
                  /\/\/\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

That's 240Kg of fuel for the astronaut, and 2460Kg to move the fuel itself; and it gets worse as you add more and more layers.
Now let's consider the original question - what if the astronaut was physically smaller? For convenience, I'll scale them to 1/3rd their original size, and our rocket looks something like this:
                       ()
                     /\/\/\
                  /\/\/\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

But there's something wrong with our first layer of fuel now; if we zoom in:
  ()  
/\/\/\

We realise that we have three times as much fuel as we need at this point in the journey. In fact, if we flew just this first layer, we'd find it would look more like this:
()/\
/\/\

We burn 20Kg of fuel to move the astronaut, but we burn another 20Kg to send the last 20Kg of fuel on a round trip, only be left in the rocket when it gets home. Sending fuel to the moon and back just to not be used is pointless and wasteful, so let's remove the leftover fuel, and the fuel that was used to move it:
()
/\

This looks much better, though we've still only made a tiny 40Kg dent in our 2700Kg rocket - nothing to get very excited about. If we look at the whole thing again:
                       ()
                       /\
                  /\/\/\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

Now we see the same problem on the second layer, but even worse (double in absolute terms, in fact); we're supplying 120Kg of fuel to move 40Kg of payload, for a mass ratio of 4:1, and wasting 80Kg of fuel. Let's fix that:
                       ()
                       /\
                      /\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

Same for the third layer:
                       ()
                       /\
                      /\/\
                    /\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

And then the fourth:
           ()
           /\
          /\/\
        /\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

That's looking much better - but despite trimming out so much fuel, our delta-v requirement is still met. Each layer can deliver 2Km/s of delta-v for all the layers above combined - that is to say, this rocket can still lift both the astronaut payload, and the rocket itself.
For a sense of scale, let's look at our original rocket, then all the mass that was removed at each layer, then the final rocket again, but laid out on their sides in something more like a rocket shape:

Original
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>oo
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>o

Removed
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>o
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>o

Final
>>>>>>>o
>>>>>>>>

Hopefully it's clear that compared to the original rocket, the removed payload & fuel is 2/3rds of the total (for 2/3rds of the payload) and the final rocket is 1/3rd the size, with 1/3rd the payload. Total rocket size scales exactly proportionally with payload size, while still having enough fuel to move itself and its fuel reserve.
"But what about..."
The rest of the command module
Of course, an astronaut isn't going to have a great time if you just hand them a tank with 2.5 tons of fuel and light one end; the payload really needs to account for the command module as a whole, not just the passengers, plus the dry mass of the service module. On Apollo 11, that's 11.8 tons (5.7 for the CM, 6.1 for the dry SM).
But the demonstration above still works exactly the same. Make () stand for 4 tons of dry CSM, and /\ stand for 4 tons of fuel, and go through all the steps again - you'll see that the fuel needs scale exactly the same. If you reduce the mass of the CM, you reduce the mass of the final rocket - and because the SM is almost entirely fuel storage and engine (functionally a rocket module for the lunar orbit insertion and trans-Earth injection), as the CM scales down & the fuel scales down, the SM scales down with it.
The 30 amp wires/cameras/stereo boombox
As mentioned above, electrical systems only account for 25% of the mass of the vehicle. The CM has 6m^3 of habitable volume out of 13.82m^3; that gives you 40-45% of the volume that scales with the crew, even before you include the structural volume, which primarily exists to keep the pressure vessel around the habitable volume intact. The pressurised volume is 10m^3, meaning (at absolute most) the flight systems, computers etc. takes only 40% of the volume. 60-75% of the CM will scale with the crew to a greater or lesser extent.
I've taken the original question literally, and assumed any tech stays exactly the same - but there were excellent points made in the comments about the hand-crafted computer parts. For example, memory cores & rope memory in the flight & telemetry computers were entirely hand-woven, and tiny hands can weave tiny equipment.
On the lunar lander, only 250Kg was allocated for scientific/experimental equipment - and even some of that is going to scale, unless we're asking 1/10th size astronauts to use full size shovels.
I'm still running my numbers with the assumption that electrical is a fixed lower limit, but that still leaves 75% of the mass potentially available to scale, and so 75% of the final rocket size.
The real, bigger numbers
I've only run the numbers here for individual astronauts, part of the way around the moon - saving 1.8 tons isn't all that much when we're talking about a 2,800 ton Saturn V. So let's run the baseline numbers for just removing the crew, no CM/LEM/CSM or engine changes:
Base mass of crew: 215Kg
2/3 crew in lunar lander: 143Kg
Fuel saved in CSM on 1.1Km/s Trans-Earth Injection: 96.7Kg
(Mass Ratio 1.45:1)
Fuel saved in LEM on 4.6Km/s lunar landing & return: 533.7Kg
(Mass Ratio 4.72:1)
Total mass reduction in lunar orbit: 845.3Kg
Total mass reduction in CSM for Lunar Orbit Insertion: 1145.3Kg
(Mass Ratio 1.36:1)
Total mass reduction in S-IVB upper stage on 3Km/s TLI: 3152.5Kg
(Mass Ratio 2.75:1)
Total mass reduction in initial rocket mass (for 9.3Km/s burn to LEO): 70,326.1Kg
(Mass Ratio 22.3:1)
Simply by removing 215Kg of astronauts, you reduce the initial rocket mass by 70 tons, six times the dry payload weight, and more than the entire wet weight of the CSM & LEM
Hopefully that gives an idea of why there is so much room available for reducing the size of the Saturn V launch vehicle, or using a smaller alternative.

@parasoup Oh, good spot - I read the 1/10 in the question as volume so my estimates are too conservative, but you're exactly right; for a constant delta-v & specific impulse, the ratio of wet to dry mass is constant, so a smaller command module means a proportionally smaller fuel mass.

I see, you reduced the payload from three men to one man essentially. My question is not really equivalent to your premise, because the scaling factor of 1/10 or 1/100 is important to the whole scenario (the colon-notation was unclear? my bad, sorry). Your work sheds much light on what could have been accomplished, though, so I take it as realistic approach rough estimate. Thank you for your work! Cool links!

By far the largest mass that needs to be lifted is the rocket fuel. Even with no cargo at all, a rocket needs to be a certain size to lift its own fuel. I am surprised you didn't mention that.

@fishinear That's correct; most of the fuel is expended lifting other fuel to the point where it's burned. If I remove the payload, I can also remove the fuel that was used to lift that payload; then I can remove the fuel that was used to lift that fuel; then remove the fuel that was used to lift that fuel... and so on. This is why the rocket equation is exponential.

Another commenter mentioned JAXA's SS-520 rocket that lifted a nominal 4kg to LEO, and only weighed 2.6 tons; going from LEO to a lunar round trip only increases the delta-v total from ~9.5km/s to 14.5km/s, so with exponential increase your rocket is e ^1.5 which is about 4.5x the rocket size, or 11.7 tons.

I mentioned that reducing the payload to 1/3rd will (loosely) reduce the rocket size to 1/3rd, though I may not have called it out clearly; do you feel that's insufficient?

@Antares The notation was perfectly clear, my late-night reading skills are to blame :D I reduced the number of astronauts rather than the size of each as we have existing evidence that will answer your question "Can we build a downsized one and reach the moon equally well?" As far as the rocket equation is concerned, the mass ratio (of wet to dry mass, or payload to full rocket) is fixed, and it doesn't change if that payload is one normal-sized astronaut or multiple tiny astronauts.

Because your payload also includes the flight systems to travel to the moon and back, which won't scale as well as the rest of the vessel, there's a lower bound to the payload of maybe 25%-33%; so without changing the mission profile I'd estimate your minimum rocket size at 1/3rd the size of Saturn V, or about 1,000 tons.

That's where it gets interesting, of course - launching tiny astronauts (1/10th height means 1/1000th the mass, so 70g each!) in a space capsule weighing a couple of kgs stuck to the side of massive flight computer that weighs 500-1500kgs may not be a popular choice, so there are other mission profiles you could consider. For Artemis, the plan is to send a 100 ton lunar lander as a separate mission to lunar orbit, and have the astronauts rendezvous there. You could launch the flight service module on one rocket, then the astronauts & capsule on a much smaller rocket, and dock them in LEO.

So, in summary: You can use a smaller rocket than Saturn V to send smaller astronauts to moon and back. There are practical lower limits, because you need flight systems for the mission and additionally there are inefficiencies during launch that become dominant for small payloads. Because of the smaller payload and the relative size of astronauts/capsule to flight systems, your mission may benefit from a different mission profile (e.g. earth-orbit rendezvous, or even direct ascent) or more efficient & lower thrust-to-weight rockets.

Also larger engine bells are simply more efficient than smaller ones. So there are some absolutes in the equations besides air resistance.

I find the assumption that electronics could not be scaled down interesting. The guidance computer of Apollo was assembled by hand, weaving copper wire around. Since 1/10 humans could weave 1/10 wires with equal ease, couldn't the guidance system be 1/1000 the weight?

@MattieuM. One thousandth of the weight is probably way too much, but I was thinking the same. Smaller humans could build smaller circuits, resistances and capacitors because in 1960 the size of those was related to the smallest that humans cound craft them manually. Also, the wires would be much shorter. All in all, the electrical and electronical equipment could also be downsized greatly.

Actually, I would think a lot of the electronics could be made smaller.  The big limitation with mini computers was how small human hands could make the machines that made the transistors. Small hands mean smaller toolwork meaning smaller electronics should be possible.  Your circuit boards themselves would be proportionally thicker, but width and height? You can just make everything smaller and lower voltage for most of what you need to do.

The only things that would have to be "big" is the radar and antennae because you are still working with the same actual distances.

@Nosajimiki: I understand that antennae need to be the correct size for the wavelength they are supposed to receive... couldn't it be possible (by physics) that micronauts can achieve the communication with shorter wavelengths as well? Maybe there are limitations bc of atmospheric influences (ionosphere etc.) but I do not know the details/effects really.

@Antares Given weight considerations, I would not imagine that the mission would have used bigger antennae than they needed for the tech they had available at the time.  As for actual sizes, it's hard to find exact dimensions but: based on photos, the transponder antenna was about 150x20x20cm.  The mission also used a 79cm parabolic dish and two scimitar antennae which from photos appear to be about 50x30x2cm each.

@AndrewArmstrong: Outstanding analysis & explanation in your Edit! Nice work! I conclude that your calculation example shows that also 1:10 or 1:100 scales for micronauts should reduce the size of the rocket significantly. Maybe not exactly to 10m or 1m but 75% of the factor might be plausible. So, IF there are logical contradictions, they lay somewhere else than in the fuel constraints because deltaV to the moon is reachable still. Like e.g. material strength or radiation shielding and others which don't scale at all (like antenna)

@AndrewArmstrong: I accepted this answer, because you clearly put the most effort into trying to find answers/solutions to the question and explain it in a detailed way, so I could even gather more principle knowledge and not "just knowledge". You tackled the rocket equation, which I didn't dare, but now can see how it works! To all others, I would have accepted more than one answer, If it would have had been allowed.

Previous answers have shown how small the mass of the astronaut is to the life support systems and capsule to maintain them. I believe in the early days, NASA looked at midgets, dwarves, and lilliputians, to see whether any savings could be made. I think it gets a passing reference in 'The Right Stuff' but I may be wrong on this. The conclusion was that such people took up less room but generally had other health problems. A more hopeful tack would be to try and find someone who has reduced life support needs.
A double amputee made a good argument for being an astronaut (New Scientist, about 1990, according to memory). They said they had 20% less mass, but they also had 20% less metabolism. The legs that he hadn't got were not always a help in weightlessness, but his skills with making do with what he had might help. Less space-suit (though one size fits all designs don't help here).

Interesting point. Never thought about that.

This is a long-standing discussion (most recently, all-female crews for Mars missions were suggested). Really though, the marginal benefit of sending lighter humans is almost never "worth it" because they are just such a small mass-fraction of even long-duration missions. Compared to the rest of the spacecraft rocketry systems, people just don't mass much and designing the envelope so tightly that only very specific people can use it, doesn't make much sense when you already need to safety margins and could bring a couple extra kg of fuel to compensate.

The problem is drag.  Specifically, the drag equation $F_D\, =\, \tfrac12\, \rho\, v^2\, C_D\, A$.  Go ahead and look that up at Wikipedia, but the only thing I want to call attention to is that the drag force depends on the area A, but the amount of energy in the fuel depends on the volume of the fuel, which is not much less than the volume of the rocket.  That means that a rocket 1/10 the size has roughly 100x less drag - but 1000x less fuel!
According to this stackexchange conversation the drag on a Saturn V rocket peaked at 460,000 pounds, or about 7% of the original mass of the rocket and about 50% more than its payload of 311,152 pounds.  I don't think it's valid to say that if the drag goes over the total payload then the rocket can't fly without any, but I'm not sure.  If it were true, then the drag need only "increase" (relatively) by a factor of 1.67, which means the actual length could only decrease by that factor

Thanks, interesting computation, I did not think about drag before. I'll have a look at it!

@Antares it's usually not very significant. For the Saturn V, aerodynamic drag losses only amounted to 40 m/s of delta-v, despite the forces being as high as mentioned...gravity losses were much worse (both for the same reason, the slow liftoff: https://web.archive.org/web/20140812072426/http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=9959.msg189860#msg189860). But it gets a lot worse as rockets get smaller. Looked at another way, a shorter rocket has to push a larger fraction of its mass in air out of the way during ascent.

Looking at it from the angle of the smallest rocket proven to get something to the surface of the moon, make a soft landing, and then return it from the moon's gravity well to earth and have it land without burning up, there are a few examples aside from Apollo.
The Soviets sent several sample return missions that were successful. The launch vehicle was a "Proton Booster Plus Upper Stage and Escape Stages", I think the mass was around 700,000 kg (Proton-K).
More recently China has twice successfully brought back samples from the moon using a Long March 5 vehicle, which is around 850,000 kg at launch.
The Saturn 5 was more like 2,800,000 kg at launch, so at a minimum it would appear that mini-NASA would have to build a rocket that was around 1/3 the mass of Saturn V.
The height of the Протон and 长征 5 rockets were/are something like 50m and 57m respectively, compared to 111m for the Saturn V.
So in terms of scale of a 0.1 tall human, the rockets are ~3x heavier and ~5x as tall compared to a Saturn V viewed by a 1.0 human.

Thanks! A nice rundown of the possibilities and interesting comparisons to the other nations's vehicles! Your conclusion sounds very plausible.

You'd need a smaller and simpler rocket.
The only question for the rocket is the mass (and to a certain extent the volume and shape) of the payload. Reduce the mass of the payload, reduce the size of the rocket.
And we did this. Sort of.
Mass of your mini-astronauts

For the matter of scaling, a mini-human shall be 17.5cm (0.175m) tall on average... Thus you could assume a scaling factor of 1:10.

This is great, because volume decreases with the cube of the height... if humans were regular solids. They aren't, but mass still decreases rapidly with decreasing height.
A roughly 40 cm newborn masses only 3.4 kg on average. That's 4.5 times shorter than a full grown 1.8m human, but 20 times less massive. Your astronauts are half that size, so I'll roughly estimate them at 1.5 kg. Basically negligible mass. That's a roughly 1:45 mass ratio.
More like astronaughts, amirite?
Mass of a mini-lunar mission
When you scale down the humans, everything else scales down. Consumables (air, water, food), volume of habitable space, their clothes, tools, instruments, etc. Some things remain the same size, like their computers.
Apollo 11 massed about 50,000 kg on the launch pad. Using our 1:45 ratio naively we'd get a mass of about 1100 kg. But some things won't scale down, so let's be conservative at 5000 kg.
Why don't computers get smaller? Heat.

True, they were large and handcrafted that time. But micro-nauts have micro-hands (as were stated in one of the answers/comments). So they would be able to manufacture smaller devices as well. UNLESS there are physical constraints which do not allow shrinking of electrical components beyond a certain limit without having high-tech available...

While things like controls and buttons might get smaller, yes, there are physical constraints on the size of the actual electronics.
Material science limits how small one can make a computer before it overheats. Resistance is inversely proportional to cross-sectional area: thicker wires have less resistance and give off less heat. And as you make things smaller it's harder to move heat away from sensitive components tightly packed together.
Dissipating heat is an even worse problem in spaaace! There's three ways to move heat: convection (moving air, like with fans), conduction (touching), and radiation (electromagnetic radiation, not ionizing radiation). There's no air in space, so convection doesn't work. There's nothing for the spacecraft to touch, so conduction doesn't work. Only radiation works, and it's inefficient compared to the others. If you look at the ISS, some of what look like solar panels are really radiators.
While they might be able to make a physically smaller computer, it would generate more heat. That heat would have to go somewhere. To avoid cooking the computer, or the occupants of the spacecraft, it would need large, heavy heat transports and radiators.
We still have this problem, on Earth and in space. It's why your phone or laptop gets hot and sometimes slows down or even shuts down to protect itself. It's amongst the reasons why spacecraft fly with such seemingly under-powered computers.
We already did this (with robots)
I could run the numbers, and I tried, but multi-stage rockets are hard. Fortunately, the Soviets did it. Sort of.
Luna 16 was a Soviet robotic sample return mission to the Moon in 1970. The payload massed about 5,725 kg at launch, similar to our rough estimate. This gives us a floor for the smallest feasible lunar landing and return mission. Our tiny astronauts would need more mass for their life support, but that may be balanced by needing fewer electronics because humans are doing that work.
Luna 16 launched on a Proton K/D rocket. This massed in at about 700,000 kg, far short of Apollo 11's 3,000,000 kg. Sending 6000 kg to the Moon requires a cheaper heavy-lift vehicle, still expensive, but not a budget-busting super-heavy like the Saturn V. The US could have used the simpler and cheaper Saturn 1B.

Nice way of approximate the mass reduction! Also a good example for a small payload that did land on the moon and returned (samples) to earth! Totally forgot about them. Seen from the mass aspect of the scaling the truth seems to be somewhere there, as other answers also agree. Why computers have to remain in size, I don't understand fully, though.

@Antares Heat, always a problem with computers, much worse in space. I've added a section to the answer explaining.

Let's look at a few issues regarding automobiles (work with me...).
Issue #1

Only about 14%–30% of the energy from the fuel you put in a conventional vehicle is used to move it down the road, depending on the drive cycle. The rest of the energy is lost to engine and driveline inefficiencies or used to power accessories. (Source)

Issue #2

Average human adult weight is (very) roughly 150lbs or 68kg.
Your average automotive sedan weight is 3,628lbs or 1,646kg.

Which means if we put four adults into the sedan (and we treat this really roughly because it's late and I'm about to go to bed), then only 14% of the energy actually used to move the vehicle is actually used to move the people.
And when we put those two issues together in a best-case scenario (meaning we're intentionally trying to answer your question with a "yes, you can scale down the Saturn V rocket!") we get...
A whopping 4% of the fuel you put into your car is actually used to move four adults down the road.
<soapbox_mode: on>If you're hating yourself now for using gasoline rather than riding a bike... you should feel that way.<soapbox_mode:off>
Now, let's reduce the weight of the four adults (yes there were only three astronauts, but work with me) by 90%. 600lbs becomes 60lbs. Can we significantly make the car smaller?
No, not really... Well, kinda... but that's not the point
Fuel, safety features, necessary traction on the road, the size of your radio.... Physics doesn't change just because the people are smaller. Can a smaller vehicle exist? Of course! But if you want the air bags and the weight on the road when there's ice and to make the federal government happy that you're as safe as possible on the road and still have all the gasoline necessary to get from A to B in a timely manner...
No, not really. Not enough to matter.
Why?
Because to answer your question we're not talking about sedans on an interstate highway where there's more rules affecting safety than there are rules of physics (haha... work with me) and those rules affecting safety can be changed to make the vehicle lighter and smaller.
No, what we're talking about a Saturn V rocket (2,778,299kg), which had as its sole purpose putting a lunar lander (14,900kg), command service module (28,801kg), and three adults (204kg) into space. That's 98.4% of the rocket to put 1.6% into space. As was pointed out by an earlier commenter, that ratio more-or-less remains stable... but what, really, is changing?
It's 1960s tech. The computer's mass won't change, or the lights, or the electrical wires. Not even the heaters, though they wouldn't need as much input because, theoretically, you're housing 20 kg worth of occupants rather than 204 kg. But I can't justify more than a 1,000 kg change to a 2.9 million kg rocket. Remember, the service module and lander fuel will change for the sake of 180 kg, but you still need the bell housing and the fuel containers (a bit smaller...) and all the electronics and safety equipment... I just can't justify it.
Conclusion
You could reduce the Saturn V's size and mass by a tiny bit, but it's such a tiny bit that it's not worth talking about. You'd basically need the Saturn V to push everything into space even if no one was aboard.
Note that the Saturn V had a purpose. Change the purpose and you change the size of the rocket. We're putting the service module into lunar orbit and landing the lander on the lunar surface — then getting home. And you need the full-scale Saturn V to do that.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I think a more nuanced version of this answer could be good and you've made some interesting points in the comments. I think it boils down to: fuel and rocket scale with payload so we can ignore that, talking about the percentage that is fuel/rocket is I think what's upset people. Life support payload (and life) mostly scaled with human size. Science payload mostly doesn't scale with human size. So the question is how much of the payload is life support (Air, food, AC units, space suits, living area, beds, water, heaters, toilets ...)

This is bollocks. The claim about "reducing 1.6% to 1.4%" completely misses the point that you now only need 7/8th of the fuel, a whopping 12% reduction on top of that meagre 1.2%. But it also misses the point that a 10 kg human doesn't need 1 kg/water a day. Which in turn means you don't need the fuel for that either.

@MSalters Why do you need only 7/8 of the fuel? The humans dropped in weight, as would their seats. You'd get a very small reduction in cabin size because all the equipment must still be there (lights, computer, wires...) and none of that changes mass because of the humans. A 12% reduction in the total is 333,396kg, but the original payload (including the humans) was only 43,900 kg! Even 12% of that is 5,300 kg (five metric tons) just because your human weight dropped from 204 kg to 20 kg? I can't justify more than a 1,000 kg change to a 2.9 million kg object. No appreciable change.

@RichardTingle The Apollo 11 didn't have beds or toilets. The heating system wouldn't change size, only the amount of fuel needed to run it (1960s tech!).  It's worth looking up what the Apollo capsules actually looked like because other than for a minor fuel change due to the loss of 180 kg of humans, some food and water, and the fuel to move that paltry amount of mass, nothing else changes. They lived in a closet for all that time.

@JBH: You only need 7/8th of the fuel because 1.4% is 7/8th of 1.6%. (Your original estimate). The computer doesn't shrink by 1/8th, that's true. But the humans and their life support systems do shrink by 90%.

@MSalters I changed my answer to avoid the conflict and be more specific about just how much I think the payload would change.

No, there's just too many problems from manufacture to successfully taking off. You'd need to handwave so many things you might as well handwave the lot.
They couldn't build it, they couldn't take off, and they couldn't land these people on the moon. We could maybe do it with modern tech, but it's definitely not doable in the 60's. And we'd never be at this stage of tech if we were that big, many of the preliminary steps would never have happened. You need to fly before you go to space.
However it could be done if the people were shrink rayed, and didn't have to do anything except stay alive, but the tech and backup team were normal sized.
Otherwise it's just Fantastic Voyage, but in space. A nice story.

Thanks, good thinking! Cool you linked Fantastic Voyage as original and not some remake. I have to rewatch that again, the trailer looks remarkable for 1966 film special effects.

Flying would actually be much easier and require much lower tech levels. You might be able to ride a large bird and mere muscle power might be enough to flap artificial wings and fly Icarus style.

@quarague: I am fairly sure "flying" here is not ment literally but in the sense of "mini-humankind has to know how to build airplanes and master the tech before it can go on build rockets to the moon" (i.e. being able to reach super-sonic and later escape velocities). Your analogy to birds as proof-of-concept for airplanes in the micronauts scale is interesting though.

Yup. 60's electronics and manufacturing weren't limited by the size of the machinist's hands. It is not "realistic" to assume smaller humans would be notably further ahead in microelectronics or precision manufacturing
